# haproxy + lua, how can we choose among 2 backends based on query param value

Tags: lua, haproxy

I have an api with the following endpoint and query params:

```
/myService/myrequest?param1=value1
/myService/myrequest?param1=value2
```

my problem is if param1's value is 'value1' then the backend should be chosen as 'backend1' but if the param1's value is 'value2' the backend should be chosen as 'backend2'. I am trying to use Lua for this purpose.

my questions are:
1. Can it be done without Lua and using haproxy only?
2. if with Lua, how we can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HAProxy ACLs directly to acheive what you want, namely by using [urlp](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#7.3.6-urlp):

```
frontend myfrontend

# your bind statement and other options
...

acl param1_eq_value1 urlp(param1) value1
acl param1_eq_value2 urlp(param1) value2

use_backend backend1 if param1_eq_value1
use_backend backend2 if param1_eq_value2
default_backend <your_default_backend>
```

Comment: Can I use a regex instead of equal?

Comment: Yes, if you use urlp_reg, e.g. urlp_reg(param1) my_regex_.*
https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#7.3.6-urlp

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in pure nginx, basically something like:

```
if ($arg_param1 = 'value1') {
  proxy_pass    'localhost:1000';
}
if ($arg_param1 = 'value2') {
  proxy_pass    'localhost:2000';
}
```

Here I'm assuming you just want to set the upstream.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but the problem is we have only haproxy setup right now and can not move to nginx.